# Body must only contain state mutability label: Vyper

Tags: vyper

I have an interface that I'm making:

```py
interface IAggregatorV3:
    @view
    @external
    def decimals() -> uint8:
        pass
```

However, I'm getting this compile error:

```
Body must only contain state mutability label
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message error is saying that instead of `pass` the body of the function must only contain a state mutability label, for example: `view`, `pure`...

Try the following (example based on documentation):

```
interface IAggregatorV3:
    def decimals() -> uint8: view
        
@external
def test(some_address: address):
    IAggregatorV3(some_address).decimals()
```

Standalone interface (remove `interface IAggregatorV3`)

```
@external
@view
def decimals() -> uint8:
    pass
```

Also, it is not necessary the `external` visibility type for an interface definition since the interface can be used to make external calls. Declaring and using Interfaces in Vyper [here](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interfaces.html#interfaces).

More about mutability in Vyper [here](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/control-structures.html#mutability).

Comment: This isn't true when importing interfaces though. Imported interfaces use the standard vyper syntax. https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interfaces.html?highlight=interface#importing-interfaces

Comment: If I import the interface as you suggest, it can't find any of the functions

Comment: So you need to provide more details, if you are defining a standalone interface and how are you importing it. Can't understand what you are trying to do, sorry. I only compiled the code.

Comment: ahh, fair enough. That should be a separate question. Thanks.